# Running into NSPOSIXErrorDomain in Swift 5.1 playground executing a local process

Tags: swift-playground, swift5

I'm running into a domain permission error when attempting to execute a terminal command through a Process() instance in a playground. I'm assuming I have to turn off domain checking somehow, but I'm not sure how to do it. I was also unable to find an answer to a similar question here if it can be worked around with code. My apologies if this has already been asked.

Running Xcode Version 11.2.1 (11B500)
Swift 5.1.2
MacOS

This script runs the 'p4' command (Perforce SCM command line application) to pull a list of running jobs and prints them.

```
import Foundation

NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { exception in
    print(" Exception thrown: \(exception)")
}

func shell(_ args: String...) -> Int32 {

    var returnCode: Int32

    let task = Process()
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path_to/p4")
    let outputPipe = Pipe()
    let errorPipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = outputPipe
    task.standardError = errorPipe
    task.executableURL = url
    task.arguments = args
    do {
        try task.run()

        print("Running the task\n\n")

        let outputData = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let errorData = errorPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()

        print ("Raw output:\n\tOutput data:\n\t\(outputData)\n\tError: \(errorData)\n\n")

        let output = String(decoding: outputData, as: UTF8.self)
        let error = String(decoding: errorData, as: UTF8.self)

        print ("Decoded output:\n\tOutput data:\n\t\(output)\n\tError: \(error)\n\n")

        returnCode = task.terminationStatus
    } catch {
        print(error)
        returnCode = -1
    }

    return returnCode
}

shell("monitor", "show", "-ael")
```

The playground returns the following:

```
Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"
```

If additional info is required or would be helpful please let me know.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated, and thank you for your time and consideration.

Regards,
Scott